# Mouseout and closing dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

I have a link to show a dialog by hovering it, I would like to know if there is a way in which :

- If I hover the link and the dialog shows but i don't enter into the dialog, and I mouse out the link the dialog will be closed. (I could do this with mouseleave function)
- But I also have the possiblity to do enter the dialog (mouse out the link) moving the cursor toward the dialog, to see/click on some information on the dialog without closing it.

I know it sounds a bit confusing but hope you guys can guide me out.

Here is my photo of the dialog:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEfzI.png

Comment: When you mouseenter the link then make `jQuery("#dialog_id").show();` and also have the same code when you enter the dialog. And `jQuery("#dialog_id").hide();` for leaving the dialog or link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to set a timeout with setTimeout()?

```js
$("#link").mouseout(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active")
  }, 2000);
});
$("#dialog").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active")
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem by delaying the closing of the dialog.

Comment: If this was the right answer, please mark it as the right answer, thanks!